# Finding out is user fully completed download or not in C#

Tags: c#, download, webclient

I have created a class that downloads files from a web client and the completed method returns a message in the console of the downloaded yes or no. This works, but is it also possible to read out how big the file is before downloading, and if the download is interrupted and not completely downloaded to delete this file?

How can I add this detection? I was thinking to read out the size of each file via readallbytes to get the size but so far without success

This is my code so far

```
public class FileDownload
{
    private volatile bool _completed;

    public bool DownloadCompleted
    {
        get
        {
            return _completed;
        }
    }

    public async Task DownloadFile(string address, string location)
    {
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            Uri Uri = new Uri(address);
            _completed = false;
            client.Headers.Add("Authorization", await Header.getAuthorizationHeader());
            client.DownloadFileCompleted += new System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
            client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(DownloadProgress);
            client.DownloadFileAsync(Uri, location);
        }
    }

    private void Completed(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Cancelled == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Download has been canceled.");
            _completed = false;
        }
        else if (e.Error != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Download error!");
            _completed = false;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Download completed!");
            _completed = true;
        }
    }

    private void DownloadProgress(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Displays the operation identifier, and the transfer progress.
        Console.WriteLine("{0}    downloaded {1} of {2} bytes. {3} % complete...",
         (string)e.UserState,
         e.BytesReceived,
         e.TotalBytesToReceive,
         e.ProgressPercentage);
    }
}

// override DownloadFileAsync timeout to 10 second
public class WebClientWithTimeout : WebClient
{
    //10 secs default
    public int Timeout
    {
        get;
        set;
    } = 10000;

    //the above will not work for async requests :(
    //let's create a workaround by hiding the method
    //and creating our own version of DownloadStringTaskAsync
    public new async Task<string> DownloadStringTaskAsync(Uri address)
    {
        var t = base.DownloadStringTaskAsync(address);
        if (await Task.WhenAny(t, Task.Delay(Timeout)).ConfigureAwait(false) != t) //time out!
        {
            CancelAsync();
        }
        return await t.ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    //for sync requests
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
    {
        var w = base.GetWebRequest(uri);
        w.Timeout = Timeout; //10 seconds timeout
        return w;
    }
```

Comment: Reading all bytes of a file to work out its size would be a bad plan. The `FileInfo` class contains a `Length` property which can tell you the number of bytes *without having to load all of them into memory*.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having complicated logic, you could download it as another name and only rename it to the correct name after the download completed. If all your temporary files followed a pattern, you could delete those files when you start the program, since they obviously were left over from a prior run that failed.

You may also want to delete the temporary file if you find out the download failed (you already know, sice you are printing it to console).